Install gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu in debian10 aarch64 not working
I am working on some project in debian10 and want to install package gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu. To do it I execute the following command apt-get install gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu. What is surprising though is that it does not seem to install the compiler. However, it does install a bunch of other files. I do a search for the package post installation and all I see is a bunch of files under some doc folder but nothing under /usr/bin. Pasting below the output of search after installation.
Package search:
root@9b779b6236b1:/usr/bin# dpkg-query -S gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/copyright
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/README.ssp
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/sanitizer
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/gomp
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/TODO.Debian
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/README.Debian.i386.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/quadmath
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/changelog.Debian.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/quadmath/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/sanitizer/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/README.Bugs
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/gomp/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/itm/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/gcc
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/NEWS.html
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu, gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/mpx/changelog.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/itm
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/NEWS.gz
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base:amd64: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/mpx
gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu: /usr/share/doc/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu-base/gcc/changelog.gz

Search in /usr/bin:
root@9b779b6236b1:/usr/bin# ls gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu
ls: cannot access 'gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu': No such file or directory

Contents of apt sources:
root@9b779b6236b1:/usr/bin# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230109T000000Z buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20230109T000000Z buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230109T000000Z buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

Please advise what is it that I am missing here?

A compiler is special.  It has a triple for building.  build-host-target.  The issues is with debian package naming scheme and possibly the setup of the gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu 'deb' file.  The compiler has both host/target as i686-linux.  To have an executable for the aarch64, you need a cross compiler.  On a i686-linux, I can install the package gcc-10-aarch64-linux-gnu - GNU C compiler (cross compiler for arm64 architecture).  I think the package gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu is not a cross compiler but a package reference to a specific GCC version.  The binary would be marked as i686 host only.

You can list contents with something like dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu.deb to see if the binary is present in the package.  You could also extract the file from the deb.  It is also possible that it randomly and erroneous put in the aarch64 packages.  It would need significant updates to build a cross compiler.

I don't have a debian system handy, but on Ubuntu which is probably similar, the cross-compiler executable is /usr/bin/<target>-gcc-<version>, not gcc-<version>-<target> like the package name.  So see if you have /usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-gcc-8 or some other variant.

Note that dpkg -S gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu isn't listing all the files in the gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu package, it's listing all installed files having gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu in their pathname - which, as I mentioned, the compiler binary /usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-gcc-8 would not match.  To list the files in the installed package, use dpkg -L gcc-8-i686-linux-gnu and I bet you'll see the compiler binaries in /usr/bin.

If that doesn't fix your problem then please state the exact package version number.

@NateEldredge Thank you for your inputs. I was able to figure it out and find the compiler with the naming convention as suggested by you. All this time I was actually looking for the opposite name. I am a newbie to debian, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

@artlessnoise Thank you. It's sorted now. I was looking for the wrong name all this time!
